# Splitting an input in to smaller fragments

Tags: python, input, split

I need to somehow convert a mathematical `input(str)` to a number,

e.g.

```
4-3*2-1+5 = ((((4-3)*2)-1)+5).
```

Current code looks like this:

```
Answer = input ('Put your answer here: ')
4-3*2-1+5
```

Somehow, I need to remake the string in to smaller fragments so that it reads from left to right, and to remake the numbers in to integers, but I have no idea how to do it.

I tried doing

```
Answer.split('+','-','*','/')
```

But it says `TypeError: split() takes at most 2 arguments (4 given)`

Also tried adding the answer to a list to see if that helped me at all:

```
li.append(Answer)
(li = ['4-3*2-1+5']
```

But I don't see anything beneficial with that..

Please help!

(I'm new to SOF, so if there's any information that's missing, please tell me what and I will try to correct it).

Comment: please don't ask questions twice. If you need clarifications, mention that on your original question

Comment: I just saw the duplicate too :/ I'm not sure what the OP wants now :) Whether he's trying to do simple string manip or write an expression parser and evaluater!

Comment: It didn't feel right just to click "Edit" and remake the whole text, but it's basically the same problem yes. I failed to ask the question right the first time, cos I'm that sh!t at programming. I do feel like this is abit more accurate though.

Comment: Flagged the other post aswell, asking to get it deleted.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to write is a **parser** and simple **evaulator** for *simple expressions*.

I would start reading any of the following:

- http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/HowToUsePyparsing
- http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples
- http://kmkeen.com/funcparserlib/

There are many other **parser** libraires, but these are just a couple.

You could also just use the [rply](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rply) library which if you have a look at the **PyPi** page has an example that directly implement and simple expression parser and evaluater just like what you're describing in your question.

Comment: How do I write this in code? I'm new to programming and have never heard of parsing before. Looked at the websites, didn't understand much.. :(

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Programming! Start learning! You are using a Programming Language called Python that has  Lexer, Parser, Semantic Analyzer, Compiler, Interpreter and Virtual Machine!

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing